# Vue, Laravel Pagination doesn't work well

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

This is my post page:

```
<template>
   
    <br/>
    <pagination
        @pageClicked="getPage($event)"
        v-if="this.getdArray.data != null"
        :links="this.getdArray.links"
      />
 <a
        :href="route('create',{region1:this.region})"
        class="list-group-item list-group-item-action w-25 float-right text-gray-200 align-text-bottom"
         style="background-color: rgb(00, 00, 00)"
         >
        
        글작성
         
 <!-- {{ this.getdArray }} -->
    </a>

    <div v-for="post in this.getdArray.data" :key="post.id">

        <a
            :href="route('show',{'id': post.id},{region1:this.region})"
            class="list-group-item list-group-item-action w-100 float-right text-gray-200 "
             style="background-color: rgb(50, 60, 60)"
            >

            {{post.title}}

        </a>

    </div>    
</template>
<script>

    import {InertiaLink} from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
    import Pagination from "./Pagination.vue";
    export default {
data(){
return{
    postdata: []
}
},
        methods: {
            check(){
                console.log(this.postRegion);
            },
             getPage(url) {
      axios
        .get(url)
        .then((res) => {
           this.getdArray = res.data;
           console.log(res.data);
      
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
        },
        props: [
            'regionN', 'posts','dArray'
        ],
        data() {
            return {region: "", getposts: [],getdArray:[]}
        },
        beforeMount() {
            this.region = this.regionN;
            this.getposts = this.posts;
            this.getdArray=this.dArray;
            // console.log(this.getposts);
            console.log(this.region);
             console.log(this.getposts);
             console.log(this.getdArray);
        },
        components: {
            InertiaLink,
            Pagination
        },
        computed: {
            postRegion: function () {

               return this
                    .getposts
                  
                    .filter((post) => {
                        if (post.region == this.region) {
                            return post
                        }

                    });

            }
            //computed 로 필요한 데이터만 반환
            //.filter 함수는 배열에 적용가능하며 배열내 각 원소에 적용

        }

    }
</script>
```

And this is my  pagination page:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="links.length > 3">
    <div class="flex flex-wrap -mb-1">
      <template v-for="(link, key) in links">
        <div
          v-if="link.url === null"
          :key="key"
          class="px-4 py-3 mb-1 mr-1 text-sm leading-4 text-gray-400 border rounded"
          v-html="link.label"
        />
        <div
          v-else
          @click="pageClicked(link.url)"
          :key="link.url"
          class="px-4 py-3 mb-1 mr-1 text-sm leading-4 border rounded hover:bg-white focus:border-indigo-500 focus:text-indigo-500"
          :class="{ 'bg-white': link.active }"
          :href="link.url"
          v-html="link.label"
        ></div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    links: Array,
  },
  methods: {
    pageClicked(url) {
      this.$emit("pageClicked", url);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

When I push list button,

something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title inertia>Laravel</title>
```

This kind of thing send by `res.data`

How can I fix it? On other people's code, res.data has data and link,
but on my `res.data`, HTML code send back.

this is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Input;

class PostController extends Controller
{

    // public function index()
    // {
    //  //
    // }


    public function create(Request $request)
    {




        $region1 = $request->region1;


        return Inertia::render('Create', ["region1" => $region1]);
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|min:3',
            'content' => 'required|min:3',
            'image' => 'image',
            // 'region1' => 'required'


        ]);



        // $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        // $region =
        //  $request->region1;

        $post = new Post();
        $post->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->content = $request->content;

        //inertia 에서의 post요청

        //function storePost() {
        //form.post('/post/store')
        //}
        //와 같이.

        $path = $request->file('image')->store('image', 'public');
        $imgpath = "/storage/" . $path;
        $post->image = $imgpath;

        $post->region = $request->region;

        $post->save();




        // $validated = array_merge($validated, ['image' => $imgpath]);
        // $validated = array_merge($validated, ['user_id' => $user_id]);
        // $validated = array_merge($validated, ['region' => $region]);



        // Post::create($validated);










        // if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        //  $image_path = $request->file('image')->store('image', 'public');
        // }


        // $post = new Post();


        // $post->title = $request->title;
        // $post->content = $request->content;
        // $post->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        // $post->region  = $request->region;


        // $post->image = "/storage/" . $image_path;




        // $posts = Post::all();

        // $b2018 = DB::table('crimes')->get();
        // $t2018 = json_decode(json_encode($b2018), true);





        // $region1 = $request->region1;

        // $posts = Post::find($post->id);



        return Redirect::route('main');
    }


    public function show($id)
    {

        $posts = Post::find($id);

        return Inertia::render('Show', ["posts" => $posts]);
    }


    public function edit($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        return Inertia::render('Edit', ["post" => $post]);
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->content = $request->content;
        $post->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {

            $fileName = time() . '_' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();

            $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/images', $fileName);

            if ($fileName) {
                $input = array_merge($input, ['image' => $fileName]);
            }
        }




        $post->save();


        $posts = Post::find($id);



        return Inertia::render('Show', ["posts" => $posts]);
    }


    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $post->delete();

        if ($post->image) {
            Storage::delete('public/images/' . $post->image);
        }

        return Inertia::render('question');
    }
}
```

i added my controller,  and i tried to fix it but it still sent request twice...

Comment: show us your controller

Comment: @Garry thanks for reading my question. I added controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is in your Laravel `back-end` or bad request in `front-end` side, sometime laravel return error in `HTML` format, if you not defined accept `application/json` in your request headers.

Try to resolve that problem first, and edit your question.

Comment: thanks for reading my question. my crud doesn't use json api server,  in spite of should i check application/json?

Comment: show us your `response` message , if my guess was right, it contains "something wrong" message.